# Defined variable is undefined in mongoDB $where's function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Long story short, I have in my MongoDB database a collection of posts and with `node.js`, `express` and `mongoose`, I'm trying to find all the documents using the [$where](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#mongodb-query-op.-where) method.

So I try this and it works perfectly, all the results, if their name includes `Jo` get returned.

```js
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  const nameSearch = "Jo";
  Post.find({
    $where: function () {
      return this.name.includes("Jo");
    },
  }).then((data) => res.send(data));
});
```

But if I do something like this, it throws me an [error](https://codeshare.io/qPM7oZ)

```js
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  const nameSearch = "Jo";
  Post.find({
    $where: function () {
      return this.name.includes(nameSearch);
    },
  }).then((data) => res.send(data));
});
```

Also, if I do this, it says that `$where` requires a string or a function.

```js
function runThis(post) {
      return post.name.includes("Jo");
}
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  Post.find({
    $where: runThis(this),
  }).then((data) => res.send(data));
});
```

Even weirder, I think, is that if I change the function inside the `$where` to an `arrow function`, no matter what I put in the function, it will return all the results

```js
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  const nameSearch = "Jo";
  Post.find({
    $where: () => {
      return this.name.includes("Jo");
    },
  }).then((data) => res.send(data));
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this function runs on the mongo server and it doesn't have access to your local variables. Mongodb uses JavaScript as a query language.

Comment: `this` works different in arrow functions

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I didnt know that `this` works different in arrow functions, but even if I try to return a simple string, not from a function and without using `this`, it still returns all the results. Anyway do you know if there's a way for me to use a variable inside the function?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski - The immediate function `this` is used in isn't an arrow function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant this part of the code `() => {
      return this.name.includes("Jo");
    }`

Comment: *if I try to return a simple string, not from a function and without using this, it still returns all the results* - can you should an example?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski
```js
Prof.find({
    $where: () => {
      return "something";
    },
  }).then((data) => res.send(data));
```
It works completely fine, even if I return false, or true, or anything else

Comment: This `$where` function should return boolean. So if you return any string which is truthy it will return all items.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i didnt think about that, but even if I return false, undefined, null or '', it still returns every result

Comment: Surely there's a query operator that looks for a substring in a field? Having to write a function for this seems wrong...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [that's the only one I found](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/), I know there's $text, but it just searches for part of the word, for example if the name I wanted to find was `Jonathan`, if I write `Jo`, it doesnt return. If I write the entire name or `Jonatha`, it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I don't use Mongoose or MongoDb.

But the documentation says the function you pass for `$where` isn't executed locally, it's [executed on the Mongoose server](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#javascript-enablement). So it doesn't have access to the variable.

But a search ([1](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/mongoose-partial-text-search-606), [2](https://sqlserverguides.com/mongodb-find-string-contains/)) suggests that the usual way to find a substring within a field is to use `$regex`. If so, and you have a user-entered string (which might contain characters that have special meaning to `$regex`), you'll want to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) them. So for instance:

```
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
    const nameSearch = "Jo";
    Post.find({
        name: {
            $regex: new RegExp(escapeRegex(nameSearch)),
        }),
    }).then((data) => res.send(data));
});
```

...where `escapeRegex` is from that linked question's answers. (Apparently JavaScript regular expression objects are supported, as well as strings using PCRE syntax instead.)

If for some reason you can't do that, you can also pass a string for `$where`, so you could create the string dynamically:

```
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
    const nameSearch = "Jo";
    Post.find({
        $where: `this.name.includes(${JSON.stringify(nameSearch)})`,
        //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }).then((data) => res.send(data));
});
```

*Normally*, writing JavaScript code in strings is a bad idea (even though Mongoose has to convert whatever function you give it to a string to send it to the server anyway), but if you need to do this kind of substitution...

Comment: (Oops, forgot the `$regex` property in the first code block. I've fixed it. If you don't see it, hit refresh.)

Answer (score 0):

## Few things from the documentation

[$where docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

### About scope

> Starting in MongoDB 4.4,
> $where
> no longer supports the deprecated BSON type JavaScript code with scope (BSON type 15)

### You should avoid using `$where`

> $where
> evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes. Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g.,
> $gt
> ,
> $in
> ).

> In general, you should use
> $where
> only when you cannot express your query using another operator. If you must use
> $where
> , try to include at least one other standard query operator to filter the result set. Using
> $where
> alone requires a collection scan.

### About variables

I have no idea, but you can try using [$let](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/)